# How do I rotate the X axis labels 90 degrees (beanplot package)?

Tags: r, graphics

[image]

I can't see all the labels on the x axis, I'm assuming that this is because they are too big and don't fit on. I've tried googling to see how I would rotate the labels but I can't see anything for the beanplot package, here is the code and plot:

```r
beanplot(Contrast ~ ROI*Condition, data=Df,ll = 0.08,
         xlab = "AM depth",
         ylab = "ERA (arbitrary units)",
         col = list("black", c("grey", "white")),
         axes=T, beanlines = "median", ylim = c(-5, 15)) 
legend(3.7, 15.8,fill = c("grey", "black"), legend = c("RH", "LH"), cex=1)
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

With `axis` you can set where you want labels (with the `x` argument), and the rotation with `srt` (among other things). I Couldn't test it tho as you didn't provided your data.

```
axis(x=1:nrow(Df), srt=90)
```

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to share my data, I have tried the following code which gives me 6 ticks but still only displays the first 2 labels and they are not rotated `axis(1,at=c(1:6), labels =c  ('8CHF LH', '8CHF RH','8CHR LH','8CHR RH','8CHZ LH','8CHZ RH'),srt=90)`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example .... (please do **not** include your data as a screenshot, that's the least useful format ...)